# How to add Value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add value to td in jquery. I have this code but not working.
Return all values for single td. I need that input [name="text-194] contain further values not all.

```
<table id="mytable" style="width: 100%;" border="1">
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $counter = 1;
                    foreach ($result_list as $key => $row) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="jakas"><p><?php echo $counter; ?></p></td>
                            <td class="numer" value="<?php echo $row->numer; ?>"><p><?php echo $row->numer; ?></p></td>
                            <td class="nazwa" value="<?php echo $row->nazwa; ?>"><p><?php echo $row->nazwa; ?></p></td>
                            <td class="input" value="<?php htmlspecialchars($row->nazwa); ?>">


                                <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="73" title="plik"]'); ?></td>

                            <?php echo '<input type="text" name="idtest" value="' . htmlspecialchars($row->nazwa) . '">'; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php $counter++; ?>
                        <script>
                            (function ($) {
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    var value = '<?=htmlspecialchars($row->nazwa)?>';

                                    console.log(value);

                                    $('input[name="text-194"]').val($('input[name="text-194"').val() + value);


                                });
                            })(jQuery);
                        </script>

                        <?php
                    }

                    ?>
```

Comment: where is this `input[name="text-194"]` in your code ?

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="73" title="plik"]'); ?></td>
 is generated here

Comment: can you try `$('input[name="text-194"]').val(parseInt( $('input[name="text-194"').val() )+ parseInt(value));` and see if that works for you .

Comment: You have your jQuery function inside your PHP loop so it's getting added multiple times. Also, you need to show us the HTML generated by the shortcode so we can help - we can't help you select elements that we can't see :)